# Displaying error using angular data-ng-show directive

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am displaying errors using data-ng-show directive. It is working fine. The only issue is that the message is displayed on the next line. The requirement is to display it on the same line.

[image: Below is the picture of how it is shown currently.]

The HTML code that I have written is given below:

```
<form name="newTopicForm" novalidate class="form-horizontal" data-ng-submit="save()">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <label for="title" class="control-label">Title</label>
            <input name="title" type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="newTopic.title" required data-ng-minlength="5" />
            <span class="error" data-ng-show="newTopicForm.title.$error.required">*</span>
            <span class="error" data-ng-show="newTopicForm.title.$error.minlength"> Minimum 5 Characters</span>
        </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I'm using the layout page (_Layout.cshtml) like this:

```
<div class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please let me know what i'm missing, Thank you.

Comment: _The only issue is that the message is displayed on the next line. The requirement is to display it on the next line._ What the requirement is again?

Comment: I want to display it on the same line, but it is displayed on the next line. I have edited the post. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code suggests, you are also using Twitter BootStrap. In twitter bootstrap 'form-control' class, element takes 100% width of column. To make it in same line, you should create seperate column as follows -

```
<form name="newTopicForm" novalidate class="form-horizontal" data-ng-submit="save()">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="title" class="control-label">Title</label>
            <input name="title" type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="newTopic.title" required data-ng-minlength="5" />            
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
              <span class="error" data-ng-show="newTopicForm.title.$error.required">*</span>
            <span class="error" data-ng-show="newTopicForm.title.$error.minlength"> Minimum 5 Characters</span>
        </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using bootstrap's horizontal form? try this:

```
<form name="newTopicForm" novalidate class="form-horizontal" data-ng-submit="save()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label name="title" for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="email" data-ng-model="newTopic.title" required data-ng-minlength="5" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <span class="error" data-ng-show="newTopicForm.title.$error.required">*</span>
            <span class="error" data-ng-show="newTopicForm.title.$error.minlength"> Minimum 5 Characters</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button> </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

You have to follow the HTML syntax specifed on the documentation, http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms